# Calling an overload with pointers without allocating new memory

Tags: c++, pointers, overloading

Consider the overloads:

```
void foo(int) {std::cout << "foo(int) called.\n";}
void foo(int*) {std::cout << "foo(int*) called.\n";}
void foo(char*) {std::cout << "foo(char*) called.\n";}
void foo(bool*) {std::cout << "foo(bool*) called.\n";}
```

While

```
foo(int{});
```

will call the first overload, what is the cleanest way to call the second overload without allocating a new int*?  Anything better than

```
foo(static_cast<int*>(nullptr));
```

Am I missing a simple syntax here?

Comment: How about `foo(int*{})`, in analogy to your example?

Comment: That was the first thing I tried.  Apparently it is illegal syntax

Comment: Huh, today I learned something.

Comment: `using intptr = int*; foo(intptr{});` should work

Comment: note that all of these allocate memory (using automatic allocation)

Comment: @Matt.  `using intptr = int*;` costs how much memory?

Comment: @prestokeys none, but `intptr{}` uses some

Comment: @Matt.  The intptr object isn't destroyed when it leaves its scope?  Isn't intptr{} stack allocated?

Comment: @prestokeys Yes that's what I'm saying ("automatic" is the official term for stack allocation)

Comment: @MattMcNabb: A temporary is created, which does not necessarily require memory allocation.  Typically you'd just be zeroing whatever register corresponds to the first argument according to the calling convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `foo(int*{})` doesn't work, and `foo((int*){})` only works on some compilers, `foo((int*)0)` is probably the shortest, easiest to understand and guaranteed to work.

Comment: GCC 4.9.2 accept this syntax, but Visual Studio 2013 does not.

Comment: @prestokeys: But I'm sure it accepts `foo((int*)0)` which is exactly the same and one character shorter.

Comment: @Ben Voigt  `std::declval<int*>()` works, and is the solution I was looking for.  Why did you delete it?

Comment: @prestokeys: Because it shouldn't.  I just read (in the Standard) that it can only be used in unevaluated contexts.

Comment: Your right.  VS2013 accepts it but GCC 4.9.2 clearly states that it "declval() must not be used!"